# I am looking for a book designed for self teaching applied/engineering mathematics. Can someone help me find a few?

Tags: education

I have used Shaum's differential equations.  Are there others that I could use that are designed for self-study?

Answer (score 0):

- **Advanced Engineering Mathematics, Zill**
- **Advanced Engineering Mathematics, Kreyszig**

Very well written text books and fun to read.

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used it, but I think Stroud Advanced Engineering Mathematics looks perfect for self-study.  Uses programmed learning techniques.  Has answers to all the tests and problems at the back and the in-chapter examples are framed as questions with worked solutions after.

[http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Engineering-Mathematics-Fifth-Edition/dp/0831134496](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0831134496)

Topics are similar to Kreyszig but perhaps bit less detailed coverage (than again sooo many people get that book and never use more than a few chapters and not really learn those).  As with Kreyszig, it contains ODE review, vector calc review, complex analysis, matrices (linear algebra), Fourier series and PDEs.  And a fair amount on numerical solution methods.  Does not contain prob/stat chapter.

(do the look inside and read the reviews to see if it appeals to you.  I would pick it over Kreyszig which I have on my shelf but never learned from.)  The Kreyszig looks prettier and is maybe a better desk reference.  But the Stroud book is designed to actually teach.